# Unable to correctly deploy an Azure Data Factory trigger through an ARM template

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-rm-template, terraform-provider-azure

I have created a Schedule trigger in my test environment data factory and put it in the "Stopped" status. I published the changes and the ARM template got generated correctly and I deployed this using Terraform into my QA data factory and I can see the new trigger in the QA factory correctly in the "Stopped" status.

Now I made the trigger as "Started" in the test factory and published the changes. The ARM template correctly shows that it is "Started" and then I deploy this template into my QA factory using Terraform and the deployment was successful.

But the status of the trigger did not change in the QA factory and continues to show "Stopped".

Can anyone advise what might be the problem or if this is a known issue in ADF?

Update : In the test environment, I deleted the previous trigger, created a new trigger directly in the "Started" status and redeployed to QA. The old trigger did not get deleted and the new trigger was created with a "Stopped" status. I checked the Terraform state file and it shows just the new trigger with "Started" status. This is strange, could someone explain?

Comment: use Github instead

Comment: @Sarang do you mean GitHub Actions instead of DevOps? Unfortunately I need to use Azure DevOps for the CI/CD pipelines and repository.

Comment: Github configuration automatically comes with data factory and so you can check in the changes in github and get all the changes in different data factory by configuring to same github account